# DJI Mavic 2 pro data are not changing on Windows SDK

Tags: c#, windows, dji-sdk

I am trying to access DJI Mavic 2 Pro data through DJI WSDK.
I was able to setup the code as per [DJI tutorial](https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/documentation/introduction/index.html)

When I print [appActivationState](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html#appactivationstate_inline), I get the status as **ACTIVATED**.

When I print [aircraftBindindState](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html#value_aircraftbindingstate_inline), I get the status as **NOT_REQUIRED**

When I print [SDKRegistrationResultCode](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html#djisdkmanager_sdkregistrationresultcode_inline), I get the status as **NO_ERROR**

When I print [ProductIndex](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/BatteryHandler.html#batteryhandler_productindex_inline), I get the status as **0**

When I print [ComponentIndex](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/BatteryHandler.html#batteryhandler_componentindex_inline), I get the status as **0**

However, when I print other drone data such as [temperature](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/BatteryHandler.html#batteryhandler_componentindex_inline), [battery](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/BatteryHandler.html#batteryhandler_getbatterytemperatureasync_inline), ...etc, I always get the same output.

My code for Mavic 2 Pro on Windows SDK is as shown below:

```
using DJI.WindowsSDK;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using DJI.WindowsSDK.Components;
using DJI.WindowsSDK.FlySafe;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace DJIWSDKDemo
{    
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DJISDKManager.Instance.SDKRegistrationStateChanged += Instance_SDKRegistrationEvent;

        //Replace with your registered App Key. Make sure your App Key matched your application's package name on DJI developer center.
        DJISDKManager.Instance.RegisterApp("c086d1c2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        }
        private async void Instance_SDKRegistrationEvent(SDKRegistrationState state, SDKError resultCode)
        {
            if (resultCode == SDKError.NO_ERROR)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Register app successfully.");

                //The product connection state will be updated when it changes here.
                DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetProductHandler(0).ProductTypeChanged += async delegate (object sender, ProductTypeMsg? value)
                {
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                    {
                        if (value != null && value?.value != ProductType.UNRECOGNIZED)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The Aircraft is connected now.");

                            while (true) {
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The App Acitvation State is: " + DJISDKManager.Instance.appActivationState);
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The Aircraft Binding State: " + DJISDKManager.Instance.aircraftBindindState);
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SDK Registeration Result Code: " + DJISDKManager.Instance.SDKRegistrationResultCode);
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Product Index: " + DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetBatteryHandler(0, 0).ProductIndex);
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Component Index: " + DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetBatteryHandler(0, 0).ComponentIndex);
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Remaining Battery: " + DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetBatteryHandler(0, 0).GetChargeRemainingAsync());
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Battery Temperature: " + DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetBatteryHandler(0, 0).GetBatteryTemperatureAsync());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The Aircraft is disconnected now.");
                            //You can hide your pages according to the aircraft connection state here, or show the connection tips to the users.
                        }

                    });
                };
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Register SDK failed, the error is: ");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resultCode.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

[image: Output after running the code is here]

The output of temperature (**System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[DJI.WindowsSDK.ResultValue`1[System.Nullable`1[DJI.WindowsSDK.DoubleMsg]],DJI.WindowsSDK.Components.BatteryHandler+d__58]**) and battery (**System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[DJI.WindowsSDK.ResultValue`1[System.Nullable`1[DJI.WindowsSDK.IntMsg]],DJI.WindowsSDK.Components.BatteryHandler+d__22]**) are never changing.

I'm expecting the output to be integer value that changes as the drone battery is being consumed

Could you tell me what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Please post your code as code, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).